# How to create a <div> row with one element that grabs extra space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a flexible row in html without using a table such that one of the row's elements grabs extra horizontal space.  I've got a basic solution here, but it seems awkward.  For example, the button has to be before the input in the div in order for everything to be on the same line, even though on the page it looks like it comes after.  Additionally, things get more cumbersome when a second button is added (not included in my example).  Does anyone know of a better way to go about this? Here is a JSFiddle, and I've pasted the code below. A valid solution would need to be flexible enough that more fixed-width elements could be added to the row easily.  Notice that in the example, the gray box can be re-sized and the text input will automatically expand.  http://jsfiddle.net/jjfPK/8/

```
<div id="grayBox">
    <div id="searchbar">
      <button>Search</button>
      <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>

<style = "text/css">
    #grayBox
    {
        width:400px;
        background-color:lightgray;
    }

    #searchbar
    {
        margin-right:70px;
        padding: 10px;        
    }

    #searchbar input
    {
        width:100%;
    }

    #searchbar button
    {
        float:right; 
        margin-right:-70px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Why not use `display: table; display: table-row; display: table-cell`?

Comment: That's a solid solution that you have. I don't see anything wrong with using it. I have used similar CSS search bars in the past. You can use other fluid layout methods, but most of them require more markup.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell - pro beard man

Comment: See my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: @mrtsherman Downside to display: table; is that some of the older browsers do not support it, *cough* IE *cough* But other than that it's a good method.

Comment: @mrtsherman I could use a table, but I'm shooting for non-table solutions.

Comment: @Alex - display table is not the same as using a table. It is great when you want table like layout without actually using tables (which are only for tabular data). If you are interested in a solution based on that let me know. IE7 is not supported. All other browsers do support.

Comment: @mrtsherman Sure, I'm definitely interested in how you would rig it up.

Comment: Dear Alex see my updated fiddle and demo in which i created as flexible as you want. Please let me know if any issues. I have used another technique to get desired layout, HTML and CSS also mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: table`. You should use this when you have a layout for nontabular data that needs to behave like a table. Not supported by IE7, but is supported by IE8+ and all other major browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/5CBS4/

requires a modification of your html to include containers for the virtual cells.

```
<div id="grayBox">
    <div id="searchbar">
        <div><input type="text" /></div>
        <div><button>Search</button></div>
        <div><button>Search</button></div>
        <div><button>Search</button></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS applies table, row and cell styles. Use `>` to target direct descendants.  Then use `first-of-type` to make the first cell as large as possible.

```
#grayBox
{
    display:table;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

#searchbar
{
    display:table-row;
    margin-right:100px;
    padding: 10px;        
}

#searchbar > div { 
    display:table-cell; 
}

#searchbar > div:first-of-type { 
    width: 100%; padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
}
```

Comment: I like this answer.  It uses more divs, but not in a hacky way, and avoids those irritating negative margins.  I'll give you credit if nobody else chimes in by Monday with something even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

See the demo fiddle: You can change the values as per your need.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jjfPK/10/embedded/result/

**Updated fiddle:** March 25

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aEyqC/1/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aEyqC/1/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div id="grayBox">
    <ul id="searchbar">
        <li><input type="text"></input></li>
        <li><button>Search</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#grayBox
{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

#searchbar
{
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

#searchbar li
{
   display:inline;           
}


#searchbar input
{
    width:80%;
}

#searchbar button
{
    float: right;
    width: 16%;
}
```

Comment: As you narrow the window the search button disappears and the input wraps

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the problem; @mrtsherman is correct.  My searchbar is resizable as well (though I used a fixed-width wrapper, so it won't change as you resize the window)